# How to filter data from REST API filter depend of nesteed field?

Tags: rest, url, filter, wordpress-rest-api

I would like to get post object depend of the value of a subfield.

My response look like this:

```
[
    {
        "id": 1,
        ...
        "acf": {
            "hidden": true,
        }
        ...
    },
    {
        "id": 2,
        ...
        "acf": {
            "hidden": false,
        }
        ...
    }
]
```

I would like to get only object with the value acf hidden to false.
I tried filter url like this :

`mysite.com/wp-json/wp/v2/posts?[acf][hidden]=false`

But it's not working as expected. The response contains all posts.
Witch filter syntax can I use about my case?